# does giving execute privileges on a package to a role, also gives execute privilege to procedures inside it?

Tags: sql, package, procedure, privileges, sql-grant

I have a package pkg1 
which contains two function `A & B`

if I grant execute privilege on a `pkg1` to a user 
will he be available to execute function `A & B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being granted the privileges for the package, a user can explicitly execute any of the procedures contained in it

as described here,

https://www.bnl.gov/phobos/Detectors/Computing/Orant/doc/database.804/a58227/ch14.htm